# What are these objects in the jmap histogram?

Tags: java, memory, jmap

I'm using jmap to get a histogram of the heap. I'm not sure what the objects are that are referred to as "[C", "[S", "[I" and "[B". Anyone know?

```
$ jmap -histo 3299

 num     #instances         #bytes  class name
----------------------------------------------
   1:          9804       19070632  [Ljava.util.HashMap$Entry;
   2:         38074        6216960  [Ljava.lang.Object;
   3:         62256        4727832  [C
   4:         19665        3124744  <constMethodKlass>
   5:         19665        2365864  <methodKlass>
   6:         57843        2313720  java.lang.String
   7:          1662        2060528  <constantPoolKlass>
   8:         21121        1842344  [S
   9:         37772        1743888  <symbolKlass>
  10:          2554        1655632  [I
  11:         63710        1529040  java.lang.Integer
  12:          1662        1264184  <instanceKlassKlass>
  13:          1515        1196224  <constantPoolCacheKlass>
  14:         24351        1168848  java.util.HashMap$Entry
  15:         18706        1047536  java.net.SocketTimeoutException
  16:          4301         784416  [B
 ...
  23:          2588         242616  [[I
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

- `[C` is a `char[]`
- `[S` is a `short[]`
- `[I` is a `int[]`
- `[B` is a `byte[]`
- `[[I` is a `int[][]`

[The JavaDoc for `Class.getName()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName%28%29) has the details.